# SQL Server MERGE statement executed at Azure DB with linked server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, linked-server, sql-merge

I have set up a linked server connection from my on-premise to Azure called `AZURE`. When I run the following code, it errors out:

```sql
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)='

MERGE [AZURE].[Test].[dbo].[Persons] AS TARGET
USING [Test].[dbo].Persons AS SOURCE ON (TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID) 

-- When records are matched, update the records if there is any change
WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.LastName <> SOURCE.LastName OR TARGET.FirstName <> SOURCE.FirstName OR TARGET.Age <> SOURCE.Age
THEN 
    UPDATE 
        SET TARGET.LastName = SOURCE.LastName, 
            TARGET.FirstName = SOURCE.FirstName, 
            TARGET.Age = SOURCE.Age;'

EXECUTE (@DynamicSQL) AT AZURE
```

The error message is the following:

> The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables.

Attempted to make the `MERGE` statement as simple as possible for testing purposes but the same error is still returned.

Comment: You seem to be expecting the `AZURE` server to understand `[Test].[dbo].Persons` as your local `[Test].[dbo].Persons`? It's going to understand `[Test].[dbo].Persons` as *its* `[Test].[dbo].Persons`, and it's going to reject the `[AZURE].[Test].[dbo].[Persons]` for being a four-part name, thus referring to a remote server. And if it didn't reject it by recognizing `[AZURE]` is actually its own name, it would be merging that table into itself.

Comment: The error is clear, you can't merge into a linked database table? It doesn't matter what you change, while you have the same target you'll get the same error.

Comment: Why use MERGE at all? This is a single UPDATE. MERGE has several quirks and in this case it's not needed at all. In general, MERGE is hardly better than separate UPDATA and INSERT statements. Don't expect good performance though - to find out matching rows the database server will have to *pull* all the data from the remote server and perform the JOIN locally.

Comment: You can limit the number of rows to only the changed ones if you use [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) on the source server and thus use only the rows inserted or updated since the last run, eg `INSERT INTO [AZURE].[Test].[dbo].[Persons](...) SELECT ... FROM [Test].[dbo].Persons AS P
INNER JOIN
     CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [Test].[dbo].Persons, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT
ON
     P.ID= CT.tID AND
     CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION = 'I';`

Comment: You can do the same for UPDATE. You'll have to make sure the remote table is the first one in the JOIN, to ensure the changes are sent to Azure and the join performed there, eg : `UPDATE ... FROM  Remote INNER JOIN (SELECT ID,... From LocalTable INNER JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES LocalTable, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT ON      P.ID= CT.tID AND      CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION = 'U') c on Remote.ID=C.ID ;`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can the change tracking approach be used across the entire database for every table? Basically, I want to sync the remote to on-prem after I restore a back up of the on-prem to Azure that will be 15 hours behind the actual live on-prem database. I was hoping to do this with minimal effort and not use transactional replication, Azure's database sync feature, or CDC of any sort as there are 950 tables and CDC doesn't seem feasible. If any good approach comes to mind about how to complete this please share.

Comment: @NickV `doesn't seem feasible` why? What you tried is the opposite of minimal and requires writing and maintaining 950 MERGE commands. And that doesn't cover monitoring the process or detecting and fixing problems. Evert time you modified a table you'd have to find and modify the MERGE statement as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It would be meta data driven. I wouldn't write 950 different MERGE statements. It would be some dynamic SQL and using the sys.tables and sys.columns tables to generate a script of 950 MERGE statements, then just execute the script.

Comment: check if this helps you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/436634c6-07de-44ce-b27c-cafa62d781cb?